# Limit the horizontal scrolling of this custom navigation

Tags: jquery, css

I have created a horizontal scroller using jquery that has left and right buttons.

```
<div id="container">
<ol>
    <li class="a"></li>
    <li class="b"></li>
    <li class="c"></li>
    <li class="d"></li>
    <li class="e"></li>
</ol>
</div>

<button id="left">left</button>
<button id="right">right</button>
```

The container has hidden overflow with relative positioning, and the contents are moved left or right in or out of view with the following jquery:

```
$('#left').on('click',function(){
    $('ol').css('left','-=100px');
});

$('#right').on('click',function(){
    $('ol').css('left','+=100px');
});
```

The problem is that these functions are infinite, and you can keep clicking forever and they will keep going further and further off screen. I'd like to limit that so that once there is no more objects to bring into view the function does something else.

I imagine there are quite a few ways to do this, but none of the ways I think of seem that elegant. For example, counting the size of the container, and the sum total of the width of the inside items, and keeping a tally of the amount of times each button is pressed and doing some constant math each time a button is pressed.

[I've made a JS fiddle of this if I've not explained it very well.](http://jsfiddle.net/kqhNr/3/)

Ideally in that example, you would never see a pink block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is if statement:

```
$('#left').on('click',function(){
    if ($('ol').css('left') != '0px') {
         $('ol').css('left','-=100px');
    }
});


$('#right').on('click',function(){
    if ($('ol').css('left') != '300px') {
        console.log($('ol').css('left'));
         $('ol').css('left','+=100px');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kqhNr/4/

Comment: Thanks man! My mind struggle to see such obvious things for some reason.